# Is there a way to score a list that have its members in another list?

Tags: python

I have two lists. The phrase list contain both words and phrases while the check list contains only words. I want to confirm if any member of the check list is a part or in the phrase list. I will give each string in the `phrase` list a score depending on its membership in the `check` list.

In the example below, `information retrieval` yields 0.5 because only one word ("information") out of two is in the `check` list. On the other hand, `wave transformation` yields 1 because both "wave" and "transformation" appear in `check`.

I have looked for how to do it but none has worked

```
score = []
phrase = ['information retrieval', 'wave transformation', 'information', 'services', 'gold coast village']
check = ['information', 'wave', 'transformation', 'village', 'services']
```

I expect the score list to contain the score for each member of the phrase list.

```
phrase = ['information retrieval', 'wave transformation', 'information', 'services', 'gold coast village']
score = [0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.33]
```

Comment: is `check` matches against `phrase` or vice versa, also can you explain `0.33` for the last score

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this problem?

Comment: Your sample score does not align with your question.  `wave` is not in both words of `wave transformation` so should have a score of 0.5 not 1...

Comment: @Devesh In `gold coast village`, only one word out of those three is in the `check` list. --> 1/3 --> 0.33

Comment: @thereal, I've edited your question in an attempt to clarify the mapping between `phrase` and `score`. If the edit doesn't reflect your intentions, feel free to revert the change and edit it as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
phrase = list(map(str.split, phrase))
score = [len(set(check).intersection(k))/len(k) for k in phrase]
```

**Output** :

```
[0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.3333333333333333]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[sum(word in check for word in elem.split()) / len(elem.split()) for elem in phrase]
```

Will return:

`[0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.3333333333333333]`

Answer (score 0):

You can write a scoring function that accumulates the scores, and returns them:

```
def scoring(phrase, check):
    scores = []
    for block in phrase:
        tokens = block.split()
        score = 0
        for word in check:
            if word in tokens:
                score += 1 / len(tokens)
        scores.append(score)
    return scores

score = []
phrase = ['information retrieval', 'wave transformation', 'information', 'services', 'gold coast village']
check = ['information', 'wave', 'transformation', 'village', 'services']

# score = [0.5, 1, 1, 1, 0.33]

scoring(phrase, check)
```

#### output:

```
[0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.3333333333333333]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the statistics module to get the scores given that each word of a phrase will count for either 1 or 0 depending if it's present or absent from the check list:

```
import statistics as stats
score = [stats.mean(w in check for w in p.split()) for p in phrase]
```

To make this go faster you should define `check` as a set instead of a list.